# How to make my YAML produces actual value of my Ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I have a yaml file,

```
---
 - time1: <%= Date.today %>
   value: "string"
```

After I load my YAML, the Ruby code is printed as string. How I get the actual `Date.today` value?

```
{"time1"=>"<%= Date.today %>"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```rb
yaml =
  <<~YAML
    ---
      - time1: <%= Date.today %>
        value: "string"
  YAML
```

Firstly you need to apply `ERB` to your string using `result` to execute Ruby code

And only after that parse it with `YAML`

```rb
YAML.load(ERB.new(yaml).result)
# => [{"time1"=>Thu, 08 Sep 2022, "value"=>"string"}]
```

Probably you skipped first step to execute embedded Ruby and interpolate into original string

```rb
ERB.new(yaml).result
# => "---\n  - time1: 2022-09-08\n    value: \"string\"\n"
```

Of course you need

```rb
require 'erb'
require 'yaml'
```

if don't use Rails